# Confused about this nested function

Tags: function, python-3.x, closures, nested-function

I am reading the Python Cookbook 3rd Edition and came across the topic discussed in 2.6 "Searching and Replacing Case-Insensitive Text," where the authors discuss a nested function that is like below:

```
def matchcase(word):
  def replace(m):
    text = m.group()
    if text.isupper():
      return word.upper()
    elif text.islower():
      return word.lower()
    elif text[0].isupper():
      return word.capitalize()
    else:
      return word
  return replace
```

If I have some text like below:

```
text = 'UPPER PYTHON, lower python, Mixed Python'
```

and I print the value of    'text' before and after, the substitution happens correctly:

```
x = matchcase('snake')
print("Original Text:",text)

print("After regsub:", re.sub('python', matchcase('snake'), text, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

The last "print" command shows that the substitution correctly happens but I am not sure how this nested function "gets" the:

```
PYTHON, python, Python
```

as the word that needs to be substituted with:

```
SNAKE, snake, Snake
```

How does the inner function    replace get its value     '`m`'?
When    matchcase('`snake`') is called,    word takes the value '`snake`'.
Not clear on what the value of    '`m`' is.

Can any one help me understand this clearly, in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a function as the second argument to `re.sub`, according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.sub):

> it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.

The `matchcase()` function itself returns the `replace()` function, so when you do this:

```
re.sub('python', matchcase('snake'), text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

what happens is that `matchcase('snake')` returns `replace`, and then every non-overlapping occurrence of the pattern `'python'` as a match object is passed to the `replace` function as the `m` argument. If this is confusing to you, don't worry; it is just generally confusing.

Here is an interactive session with a much simpler nested function that should make things clearer:

```
In [1]: def foo(outer_arg):
    ...:     def bar(inner_arg):
    ...:         print(outer_arg + inner_arg)
    ...:     return bar
    ...: 

In [2]: f = foo('hello')

In [3]: f('world')
helloworld
```

So `f = foo('hello')` is assigning a function that looks like the one below to a variable `f`:

```
def bar(inner_arg):
    print('hello' + inner_arg)
```

`f` can then be called like this `f('world')`, which is like calling `bar('world')`. I hope that makes things clearer.